# Не работает box-sizing: border-box

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/style.css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Baloo+Tamma+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>I love design</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='full_page'> 
            
    <div class='intro'>
        <div class="header">
                <h1>Design</h1>
            </div>  
    </div>

    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    
}
 
div.header {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 400px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}   

div.full_page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('../images/background_blur.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

div.intro {
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: А где он собственно в Вашем коде? `box-sizing; border-box` -  поменяйте точку с запятой на двоеточие

Comment: Класс header, забыл добавить, не работает

Comment: Проверил ваш код, работает. Как вы определяете, что не работает?

Comment: Бокс сайз не пашет, блок растягивается из за педдинга, а не должен

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что он не работает?

Comment: Ну я запускал код, и окно с заголовком увеличивается, из-за padding, а boxsizing должен это предотвратить, но он почему-то этого не сделал

Comment: по объяснению непонятно что и где ты увеличивал

Comment: @tamonsnake `box-sizing: border-box` это не вжик и адативность. У тебя в коде используется `width: 900px`, поэтому элемент фиксированно всегда будет занимать 900px

Comment: @tamonsnake, что значит _окно с заголовком увеличивается, из-за padding_? И почему это как-то должен влиять `box-sizing: border-box` у дива с классом `intro`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не пойму, почему не работает box-sizing:border-box](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170822/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-box-sizingborder-box)

Comment: @tamonsnake, не стоит задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Достаточно отредактировать текущий

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

div.h1 h1 {
  font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
}

div.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.full_page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  background: green;
}

div.intro {
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Baloo+Tamma+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class='full_page'>

  <div class='intro'>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="h1"><h1>Design</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Если нужно, что бы блоки не выходили за границу окна и не появлялись скролы, то нужно использовать свойство `overflow: hidden;`.

Все размеры заданы в пикселях. Если нужно растянуть блок на всю ширину, то лучше его размер задавать `100%` или `100vw`. Какого расположения блоков вы пытаетесь добиться? Можно прикрепить фото?

Свойство `box-sizing:border-box` нужно, что бы `padding` или `border` не влияли на размер блока.

`box-sizing:border-box` нужно задавать для `div.header`, что бы он не увеличивался.

в `div.header` вставлен текст высотой 80px, именно на эти 80px блок и увеличивается! `box-sizing: border-box` влияет только на `padding` и `border` и не влияет на увеличение блока за счет вставленного в него текста, который расширяет его.

Текст можно вынести путем `position: absolute;`, тогда блок не будет увеличиваться

Comment: Благодарю, Станислав!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `max-width`. `max-width` означает: максимальная ширина элемента, т.е. она может становится меньше, если родительский контейнер будет ужимать блок.
`width`, это фиксированная ширина, которая не станет меньше

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.full_page {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.design {
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Baloo+Tamma+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='full_page'>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="design">Design</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```